# how to hide "py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0"?

Tags: python, pyspark, py4j

Once logging is started in INFO level I keep getting bunch of `py4j.java_gateway:Received command c on object id p0` on your logs. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 45):

using the `logging` module run:

`logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

Comment: happy to help, stackoverflow rocks

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers have worked for me. Even after using the above solutions, I was still getting the logging errors.

After a long search I came across the following that solved my issue.

```
import logging
logger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logging.getLogger("py4j.java_gateway").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

I found this solution in the Databricks Knowledge base [article](https://kb.databricks.com/notebooks/cmd-c-on-object-id-p0.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to control pyspark and py4j logging is by setting the following snippet:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(<pyspark-level>)
logging.getLogger('pyspark').setLevel(<py4j-level>)
logger = logging.getLogger('pyspark')
```

For your case you should write:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("py4j").setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('pyspark').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger('pyspark')
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was nosetests overwriting all these levels. The only solution that worked was passing `--logging-level=INFO` as argument to nose. Ref: http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/logcapture.html#cmdoption-logging-level